# Write-Protect System Variables

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, environment-variables, registrykey

I'm trying to create a script to write-protect the environment variables and then unlock them whenever we need a script to update them. We've recently had a rash of "admins" that can't read and have been completely wiping out the entire `%PATH%` variable when told to add a single entry.

I've worked out how we can script that so that there's less risk of such things, but I'd also like to have `%PATH%` uneditable except for when we need it.

I've successfully created a PowerShell function that does this, however it also prevents me from removing the rule when it needs to be edited. I've left all the default permissions on the key alone, as I ONLY want to add a restriction against editing the keys themselves.

```
function regLock
{
    Write-Host "LOCKING SYSTEM ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $key = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
    $acl = Get-Acl $key
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule("Administrators", "SetValue", "None", "InheritOnly" , "Deny")
    $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl -AclObject $acl -Path $key
}

function regUnlock
{
    Write-Host "UNLOCKING SYSTEM ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES" -ForegroundColor Green
    $key = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
    $acl = Get-Acl $key
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule("Administrators", "SetValue", "None", "InheritOnly" , "Deny")
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl -AclObject $acl -Path $key
}
```

Of course if I go into regedit I can remove the lockout key, but that defeats the purpose of keeping them out of places they shouldn't be. I thought the `SetValue` permission only applied to changing/creating values, not ACL permissions.

Comment: Revoking the culprit's admin privileges would be the appropriate thing to do. Putting up hurdles like what you're asking is bound to fall on your (or your successor's) foot some day.

Comment: Not an answer but a possible solution: add some sort of watchdog (say, as a part of logon script) that will monitor relevant environment variables and ensure they are populated as per your requirements. Handling `$PATH` shouldn't be too hard: have your own pre-defined collection with minimum required entries and then just add whatever extra entries the particular maching/account has.

Comment: Ansgar, sadly that's not possible at the moment as everything we do is done as either the domain administrator or the machine's local administrator. Everyone normally uses limited user accounts, but when installing updates or new programs we have to go admin.

Alexander - That does seem like a viable solution, since PowerShell can split the variable into an array that can be checked. I might look into that.

Comment: If you can predefine what the requirements are for specific environment variables, consider setting them via group policy instead of a script.

Comment: Incredible, I didn't know it was possible to set variables via GP. This even works out better since it'll automatically repair the variables with the right one for the right machines (since we run Exchange, SQL, SharePoint, and others).